# Rename Files & Folders Keywords - Using a CSV Look Up File

Tags: csv, powershell, rename

I would like to rename files and folders based on keywords found in a CSV file.

The CSV holds the search and replace keywords that will make up file and folder names.

```
Search | Replace
Document | DTX
Processing | PRX
Implementation | IMX
...
```

- Not all the file names include each word in the file name.
- Not all the folders will include each word in the folder name
- Powershell will have to search the child item ie the folder and file
  names.
- If it finds the word (match) - Substitute from the CSV

I have looked at these threads to help me:

[Using Powershell to recursively rename directories using a lookup file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686443/using-powershell-to-recursively-rename-directories-using-a-lookup-file/1689434#1689434)

[powershell script to rename all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024439/powershell-script-to-rename-all-files-in-directory)

http://code.adonline.id.au/batch-rename-files/

I have only managed below snippet

```
$folder = "C:\Folders"               #target folder containing files
$csv    = "C:\FileNameKeywords.csv"             #path to CSV file

cd ($folder);
Import-Csv ($csv) | foreach {
  Rename-Item -Path $_.Path -NewName $_.Filename
}
```

It only replaces one at a time.

**Question:**

How can I recursively search and replace in file and Folder Names using a CSV as a look up or reference file.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please share your code along with any error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the need to look up values by other values the usual go-to data structure is a dictionary, or in PowerShell terms a hashtable. Read your CSV into a dictionary like this:

```
$keywords = @{}
Import-Csv $csv | ForEach-Object {
  $keywords[$_.Search] = $_.Replace
}
```

Then traverse your folder tree and build the new filenames by replacing each key with its respective value:

```
Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $newname = $_.Name
  foreach ($word in $keywords.Keys) {
    $newname = $newname.Replace($word, $keywords[$word])
  }

  if ($_.Name -ne $newname) {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ansgar, thank you for your code. It renamed the folders correctly. It did not rename the files inside the folder. Pardon my ignorance do I change the folder variable to $file?

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. I forgot to add the parameter `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem`, so the code as it was didn't actually recurse into the folders. Fixed.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, it renamed the child items  - thank you. One last small detail - i do get this error Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different, I set the folder to my desktop. the script is in another folder, not sure why this error is happening -

Comment: That means the original filename was not changed, so the file doesn't need renaming. Put `Rename-Item` in an `if` condition to handle this scenario. See updated answer.

Comment: Ansgar - thank you very very much for your great coding help :) . I am extremely grateful to you thank you and Great Day to you.

Answer (score 0):

ill give it a shot. I'm assuming search and replace are your headers in this scenario. this in addition to your $folder and $csv variables.

```
$csvobject=import-csv $csv 
Foreach($obj in $csvobject){ 
$search=$obj.search
$replace=$obj.replace
get-childitem path $folder |where{$_.name -like "$($obj.search)"} | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace "$search", "$replace"} }
```

The replace handles regex so u will need to make sure Any special characters are properly escaped.

Comment: Hello Monterey, I ran the code the error message Missing ( + For each($obj in $csvobject){

Comment: That's not even valid PowerShell syntax.

Comment: I apologize looks like there were some formating errors i missed when i posted. I was working on a mobile browser. @ansgar What isn't PS syntax?

Comment: The code you had originally posted. Even after your edit the `Rename-Item` will still throw an error, because the parameter `-Path` is invalid when reading from a pipeline. Please test your code before posting an answer.