# Bulk copy and rename using lookup file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a directory that contains image files named by "parent", like this:

- aaa.jpg
- bbb.jpg

I have a lookup file that matches each parent to its children.

> aaa.jpg , 111.jpg
>   aaa.jpg , 222.jpg
>   aaa.jpg , 333.jpg
>   bbb.jpg , 444.jpg
>   bbb.jpg , 555.jpg
>   bbb.jpg , 666.jpg

I need to copy each parent file and rename it as the name of each associated child. That is, I need to generate files:

- 111.jpg (a copy of aaa.jpg)
- 222.jpg (a copy of aaa.jpg)
- 333.jpg (a copy of aaa.jpg)
- 444.jpg (a copy of bbb.jpg)
- 555.jpg (a copy of bbb.jpg)
- 666.jpg (a copy of bbb.jpg)

I'm trying to use the solution posted here: [Rename Files & Folders Keywords - Using a CSV Look Up File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960480/rename-files-folders-keywords-using-a-csv-look-up-file/36963253), however after the parent is renamed to the first child, further renaming can't happen.  Any ideas on how to copy, then rename so that all children can be renamed?

Thanks

Comment: Im gonna be honest .... I have no clue what you are asking. I have read this 3 times and seriously just dont have a single clue what it is your trying to do

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to copy, then rename so that all children can be renamed?

by using `copy-item` instead of `rename-item`.

Assuming the CSV has no headers:

```
Import-Csv lookup.csv -Headers Parent, Child | 
    ForEach-Object { 

        Copy-Item -LiteralPath "c:\temp\$($_.Parent)" -Destination "c:\temp\$($_.Child)"

    }
```